# How do I compare database values in JMeter

Tags: mysql, jdbc, jmeter

I am setting some values in database using REST request via JMeter and I want to verify the set values are committed into database. I'm able to access mysql database using JDBC driver in JMeter however I don't know how to compare the output? The JDBC output is shown within JMeter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use one of [JMeter Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions) which are designed to check if returned data matches your test case.

I would do it as follows:

1. Update something via REST API call by using a JMEter variable i.e. **EXPECTED**
2. Fetch information from the database via JDBC Request and store in to another JMeter variable, i.e. **ACTUAL**
3. Use i.e. [Beanshell Assertion](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) to compare 2 variables.

Example Beanshell Assertion code:

```
String expected = vars.get("EXPECTED");
String actual = vars.get("ACTUAL");

if (expected.equals(actual))
{
    Failure = false;
}

else
{
    Failure = true;
    FailureMessage = "Difference detected, expected: " + expected + " and actual: " +     actual;
}
```